Gutenberg Group block missing Layout options
I have a simple question I was not able to fix.
My gutenberg block is missing the Layout options in its settings. I tried to enable via add_theme_support or theme.json but I can't find anything that is possibily disabling this option. As you can see on the screenshot below, there isn't the option for Layout settings on the right side column, which allow me to select inner columns to have different width size.


You will need to add a column before you can see the Layout setting.

It doesn't work, even with columns and column inside. The option doesn't exists.

It appears that you can only modify column width of a column, not a group - see on right, you have the "Group" element selected.  You have created a group. Now you need to add columns inside your group. See here, I created a group and then added columns. Now If I select a column, I can adjust width - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pgz9onye9idu34s7kekus/gutenberg.JPG?rlkey=m425fddwicm3o5sp9qhm73stc&dl=0
